# RTL - Bracket not display correctly

Tags: css

Issue facing with RTL.

Want to change this text "3 Dec 1980 (Thu)" to RTL format "(Thu) 1980 Dec 3".

Tried below 2 methods. But, either one doesn't work. Not sure is there any better method to solve this. Thanks

```css
*:after {
    content: "\200E‎";
}
*:before {
    content: "\200E‎";
}
```

```html
<p style="direction: rtl;"><span style="direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed">3 Dec 1980 (Thu)</span></p>
```

```
<div class="date-column">
  <strong>3 Dec 1980 (Thu)</strong>
</div>

.date-column{direction: rtl;} 
.date-column strong::after{content: "\200E‎"; direction:rtl;}
.date-column strong::before{content: "\200E‎"; direction:ltr;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `direction` property:

```
*:after
{
 content: '\200E‎';
 direction: rtl;
}
*:before
{
 content: '\200E‎';
 direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Updated like above. But, it renders in ltr format instead of rtl format.

Comment: Er, you'll need to use JavaScript to take and manipulate the text and rearrange the format then. If you want help with that then please first append a class specific to dates to the `span` element or give it an `id` attribute and then I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: John.. thanks.. As its coming dynamically from CMS. we cant able to change any HTML tags. Thats why trying to play only with css if possible. Sorry.

Comment: You'll have to post more HTML code (elements, not tags, rarely use the word tag unless you need to clarify something like, "there is an attribute on the closing tag of the `a` element!"). If you can find out how to construct a CSS selector to match HTML elements that are *only* date related then you're good or modify the CMS directly. Or you could always just build your own CMS like I did. ︀ If you get the CSS bit figured out you'll have to combine it with JavaScript's `document.querySelectorAll` to be able to read, modify and write the changes. Additionally: is this *that* important?